# Configure PHP Xdebug remotely with username/password?

Tags: php, xdebug

I’m trying to configure Xdebug for my project. I use PhpStorm and I would like to enable all my developers to be able to debug their code using Xdebug. All the developers work on the same dev server machine, but each developer has its own Apache directory in this machine (like : `/var/html/www/myproject/user-dev/user1/content/`), and is sftp-chrooted to it (dev has no SSH access to the dev machine, only SFTP access to their directory).

When installing Xdebug I saw we had to provide a “remote_host” which is an IP. First I don’t really understand what’s this remote host. Is it the IP from which the HTTP request must come to tell Apache to start PHP in “debug mode” ? Or is it the IP on which the developer IDE is, listening to port 9000 ? Or maybe it is the both ?

As I want several users, I saw there is a possibility with “dbgp proxy” to enable several host.

Though, this is still not convenient for me, because my developers work from their home or in the train or wherever they want and their IP address can change everytime. Also, as I said earlier, they don’t have access to the dev machine so they can’t update DBGp proxy file to add their new IP. And even if they could, it would be very inconvenient for them to change this file everytime they move.

Is there any way to enable them to debug their work using a user/password authentication, to put for example in the header of any http request they want to debug ? Or if you had any idea of a convenient workflow for this case ?..

Comment: [ask] Try to ask one or max 2 questions

Comment: 1) `xdebug.remote_host` is the address to where Xdebug will be sending requests to establish debug connection (client). So yes -- it's an IP of the computer where IDE is running. 2) For you (multiple IPs that may change often) ... using SSH tunnel is the way to go here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html